# Why are non-ASCII characters not equal?

Tags: ruby, byte

I have two test cases where a `data_valid?` method is called. The first returns `false` and the second returns `true`, why?

```
    55: def data_valid? d
    56:   crc = d[-1]
    57:   data = d[1..-2]
    58:   len = d[0]
 => 59:   binding.pry
    60:   (data ^ len) == crc
    61: end

2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefc3ceae8>):0 > (data ^ len) == crc
=> false
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefc3ceae8>):0 > (data ^ len)
=> "\xB1"
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefc3ceae8>):0 > crc
=> "\xB1"
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefc3ceae8>):0 > exit
have a good day!
F
From: /Users/rudolph9/Projects/CombustionEmissionsTesting/micro_aeth.rb @ line 59 MicroAeth::Message#data_valid?:

    55: def data_valid? d
    56:   crc = d[-1]
    57:   data = d[1..-2]
    58:   len = d[0]
 => 59:   binding.pry
    60:   (data ^ len) == crc
    61: end

2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefe83a8c8>):0 > (data ^ len) == crc
=> true
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefe83a8c8>):0 > (data ^ len)
=> "+"
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007fbefe83a8c8>):0 > crc
=> "+"
```

The following is my extension of the String class where I'm comparing the return of the custom XOR method `^`.

```
  class ::String
    ###
    # @return the first charater in the string as an integer
    def byte
      self.bytes[0]
    end

    ### 
    # XOR two strings
    # @str assumed to be a one byte string or integer
    def ^ str
      if str.class == String
        str = str.byte
      elsif str.class == Fixnum
        nil
      else
        raise "invalid arg: #{str.class} \n Must be String or Fixnum"
      end
      self.bytes.each do |i|
        str = str ^ i
      end
      str.chr
    end
  end
```

I believe it has something to do with the first comparing non-ASCII characters.  How do I properly set up the conditional?

Comment: What are the encodings of the strings?  Call [#encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-encoding) on them to check.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov `2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007f8e642eec18>):0 > crc.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007f8e642eec18>):0 > (data ^ len).encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`

Comment: I'm having issues converting the strings for comparison purposes: `2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007f8e642eec18>):0 > (data ^ len).encode crc.encoding
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xB1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from (pry):12:in `encode'
2.0.0 (#<MicroAeth::Message:0x007f8e642eec18>):0 > crc.encode (data ^ len).encoding
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xB1" on UTF-8
from (pry):13:in `encode'` how do I approach getting a common encoding?

Comment: For comparison purposes, I'm just converting them to integers `(data ^ len) == crc.byte`.  But, where I can I find more detailed information about string encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#force_encoding` to force a string into a specified encoding

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > "\xB1".encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
2.0.0-p195 :002 > eight_bit = "\xB1".force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
 => "\xB1" 
2.0.0-p195 :003 > eight_bit.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT> 
2.0.0-p195 :004 > eight_bit == "\xB1"
 => false 
2.0.0-p195 :005 > eight_bit.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) == "\xB1"
 => true
2.0.0-p195 :006 > eight_bit.force_encoding("\xB1".encoding) == "\xB1"
 => true
```

Note the default encoding for Ruby 2.0.0 is UTF-8